# jQuery Drop-Down issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, class, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu; when I click on an item I want to show the sub-menu, and hen I click or blur on another menu it should remove the previous sub-menu by removing the drop-down class. But it doesn't work.

**jQuery**

```
$('.menu_item > li ').click(function(){
    $('.menu_item .drop-down').removeClass();
    $(this).find('span').addClass('drop-down');
});

$('.menu_item .drop-down').blur(function(){
    $('.menu_item .drop-down').removeClass();
    return false;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<nav id="menu_wrap" class="container">
    <a href="index.php" class="logo"></a>
    <a href="#" id="select_menu" class="active" onclick="open_menu()">Menu</a>
    <ul class="menu_item">
        <li><input type="text" placeholder="Search in here" class="search"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Top Lists</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shops</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>
            <span>
            <a href="#">Products</a>
            <a href="#">Products</a>
            <a href="#">Products</a>
            <a href="#">Products</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Signup.php">Create Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="Login.php">Log in</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This works here http://jsfiddle.net/yxGGk/1/ not that a `span` element does not trigger `blur` event.

Comment: if you click some where else instead of clicking on search bar it won't close the sub menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there must be a cleaner way to do this, but this works for the scenario you described

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).click(function(e) {
        var $target = $(e.target);
        $('.menu_item .drop-down').removeClass();
        if ($target.parents().is('.menu_item > li')) {
            $target.parent().find('span').addClass('drop-down');
            if ($target.parent().is('span')) {
                $target.parent().addClass('drop-down');
            }
        }
    });

});​
```

And the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrismoutray/CZ4Fn/) for completeness

Answer (score 1):

Try this

[see demo](http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp8n)

```
 $('.menu_item li').click(function() {
     $('.menu_item .drop-down').removeClass();
     $(this).find('span').addClass('drop-down');

 });

 $('.menu_item li').mouseleave(function() {
     if ($(this).find('span').length > 0) {
         $(this).find('span').removeClass('drop-down');
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

if I get you right, this may be the solution:

```
$('.menu_item > li ').click(function(){
    $('ul.menu_item li span').removeClass('drop-down');
    $(this).find('span').addClass('drop-down');
});

$('.menu_item .drop-down').blur(function(){
    $('ul.menu_item li span').removeClass('drop-down');
    return false;
});
```

this removes all `drop-down` classes from all `span` within your `menu_item` class.

If you need to close the previous `drop-down` only, you need to chose it by the appropriate selectors, starting from `$(this)`.

EDIT:

NOW I see what you are up to! You need to select all elements that you want to close the drop-down menu (sections, divs), except the ones you want the `drop-down` class to be added (in your case: `$('.menu_item > li')`). For this, add another jQuery click function and change the selectors accordingly:

```
$('div').not('.menu_item li').click(function(){
        $('.menu_item .drop-down').removeClass('drop-down');
});
```

Comment: still doesn't work ! when I click on somewhere in my page, does not remove it